# Show that a function from a quotient space onto a quotient space is continuous

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous surjective map.  Let $r$ be an equivalence relation on $X$.  Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $Y$ such that for all $a,b \in X$, if $arb$, then $f(a)Rf(b)$.  Define $g:X/R \rightarrow Y/R$ by $g([x])=[f(x)]$.  Prove that

(i) $g$ is continuous

(ii) if $f$ is a quotient map, then $g$ is a quotient map

My attempt

(i)  Let $U$ be open in Y/R.  Then $\pi_R^{-1}[U]$ is open in $Y$, where $\pi_R$ is the canonical projection map from $Y$ onto $Y/R$.  Since $f$ is continuous it follows that $f^{-1}(\pi_R^{-1}[U])$ is open in $X$.  Note that $f^{-1}\circ\pi^{-1}_R=(\pi_R\circ f)^{-1}$, so $\pi_R \circ f$ is continuous.  Since $g\circ\pi_r=\pi_R\circ f$, it follows that $g\circ\pi_r$ is continuous.  Hence $g$ is continuous.

(ii)  Suppose that $f$ is a quotient map.  To show that $g$ is a quotient map we have to show that $g$ is surjective and that $U$ is open in $Y/R$ iff $g^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X/r$.  Through continuity of $g$, we already have $U$ open in $Y/R$ implies $g^{-1}[U]$ open in $X/r$.

For the other direction, let $U \subseteq Y/R$ such that $g^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X/r$.  Then $\pi_r^{-1}(g^{-1}[U])$ is open in $X$.  Now $\pi_r^{-1}\circ g^{-1}=(g\circ\pi_r)^{-1}=(\pi_R\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ\pi^{-1}_R$, so we have that $f^{-1}(\pi^{-1}_R[U])$ is open in $X$.  By assumption $f$ is a quotient map so $\pi^{-1}_R[U]$ is open in Y.  Hence $U$ is open in $Y/R$.

Now let $[y] \in Y/R$, then $y \in Y$ and since $f$ is surjective there exists $a \in X$ such that $f(a)=y$.  By assumption if $crd$ then $f(c)Rf(d)$, so for every $x \in [a]$, we have that $f(x)=f(a)$.  Therefore $g([a])=[f(a)]=[y]$, so $g$ is surjective.

Therefore $g$ is a quotient map.

Is this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: When at the end of your proof for (i) you conclude that $g$ is continuous from the continuity of $g \circ \pi_r$, it seems that you take it as a known fact that a map is continuous if its composition with a quotient map is continuous. That's okay, as long as you know how to prove this fact. But since you were able to prove correctly that $g$ is a quotient map in (ii), it seems to me that you wouldn't have any problems with that since the argument is along the same lines as that for (ii).

Comment: I'd like to add that writing $f^{-1} \circ \pi_R^{-1}$ is bad style since $\circ$ means composition of functions and $f^{-1}$ is not a function $Y \to X$ unless $f$ is bijective. You apparently mean something like "*The preimage under $f$ of the preimage under $\pi_R$ is the same as the preimage under $\pi_R \circ f$.*" In symbols one could write this as $f^{-1}(\pi^{-1}_R(U))=(\pi_R\circ f)^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Finally,  the second sentence in the last paragraph is superfluous. That consideration is only important for the well-definedness of $g$. Also note that it should read $[f(x)] = [f(a)]$ at the end of that sentence.

Comment: @Stefan:  Wow, thank you very much.  I'll keep this in mind when writing proofs next time  :)